# Box-shadow is overlapping other elements, how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css

Basically because of how HTML orders elements (the last one has the highest priority over the others) my shadows overlap other elements. If I use z-index on the first element then that is the only one that doesn't overlap, I don't know how to do it for all of them.

This is what I currently have (ignore the shadow size difference, I did it on purpose to see my problem):

[image: this is what I currently have]

This is what I should have:
[image: this is what I should have]

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
.timer-container {
  font-size: 0;
}
.timer-container .timer {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 170px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: red;
  margin: 0 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 26px 57px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 26px 57px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 26px 57px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.timer-container .time {
  height: 120px;
  font: 4em serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdd9f6;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
}
.timer-container .label {
  height: 50px;
  font: 1.125em serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="timer-container">
    <div class="timer">
        <div class="time">
            <span>12</span>
        </div>
        <div class="label">
            <span>jours</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timer">
        <div class="time">
            <span>17</span>
        </div>
        <div class="label">
            <span>heures</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timer">
        <div class="time">
            <span>48</span>
        </div>
        <div class="label">
            <span>minutes</span>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="timer">
         <div class="time">
             <span>05</span>
         </div>
      <div class="label">
          <span>secondes</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a way. Split your shadow boxes from your timers, so you can use `z-index` to put them behind the timers.

```css
.timer-container {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.timer-container .timer {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 170px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: red;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.timer-container .time {
  height: 120px;
  font: 4em serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdd9f6;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
}

.timer-container .label {
  height: 50px;
  font: 1.125em serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.timer-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}

.timer-shadow span {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 26px 57px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 26px 57px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 26px 57px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 110px;
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer-container">
  <div class="timer" style="z-index:4;">
    <div class="time">
      <span>12</span>
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="z-index:3;">
      <span>jours</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timer" style="z-index:2;">
    <div class="time">
      <span>17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <span>heures</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timer" style="z-index:1;">
    <div class="time">
      <span>48</span>
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <span>minutes</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timer">
    <div class="time">
      <span>05</span>
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <span>secondes</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timer-shadow">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```